# Dancing Dolls Problem :  on GCC  linux

Tags: c, gcc, terminal, dos, virus

As a preface, I really do not want the exact solution to my problem, just guidance. I don't want you to give me the code. This isn't homework, it's just an exercise I'm trying to solve.

I just want you to tell me how to access VDU and directly change character on same screen.

The screen is divided into 25 rows and 80 columns. The characters that are displayed on the
screen are stored in a special memory called VDU memory (not to be confused with ordinary
memory). Each character displayed on the screen occupies two bytes in VDU memory.

The first of these bytes contains the ASCII value of the character being displayed, whereas, the second byte contains the colour in which the character is displayed. For example, the ASCII value of the character present on zeroth row and zeroth column on the screen is stored at location number `0xB8000000`.

Therefore the colour of this character would be present at location number `0xB8000000 + 1`. Similarly ASCII value of character in row 0, col 1 will be at location `0xB8000000 + 2`, and its colour at `0xB8000000 + 3`.

My task:

> With this knowledge write a program which when executed would keep converting every capital letter on the screen to small case letter and every small case letter to capital letter. The procedure should stop the moment the user hits a key from the keyboard. This is an activity of a rampant Virus called Dancing Dolls. (For monochrome adapter, use 0xB0000000 instead of 0xB8000000).

Really I don't have any idea to build this code. I'm stuck at even getting started.

Comment: Which OS are you talking about?

Comment: ubuntu linux with gcc compiler...

Comment: although it was not mention with the problem that I should use gcc linux.

Comment: Please use descriptive titles with your questions. Imagine that everybody would just ask "please help me" how do you think that we would sort things. Putting it in one concise question would also be a good exercise for you to first understand your question better for yourself.

Comment: You could add a reference to the source of the puzzle? (Is it "Les us C" by Y. Kanetkar?) And there is an exact duplicate of your question, capitalization included, at [this link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/348025), is it by you, too?

Comment: This duplicate that @Francesco found looks really suspicious. In fact the only thing that was not copied was the informative title :(

Comment: I've made some edits to your question, please verify that what I've done continues to convey the question you were asking. Also, the title needs some work.

Comment: yes that post was by me through my friend's profile.That time I was not aware of even these forums.I mailed him this problem.Then exam came and till then we forgot this one...Now I am working on improving my C so this problem came again into my mind and I asked......

Comment: also if someone could tell me how to start with it ??

Comment: I actually have the answer, was about to click POST when this thread was locked up. This is really low level stuff related to Video Refresh Buffer and your information is quite right. But I don't think you'll be able to do it on Linux. This information seems to for DOS only.

Comment: If others help me to reopen the thread you'll get a decent answer. The question is not vague at all, it's just that there's not that many ppl who have worked with this and nowadays there's no reason to know it.

Comment: @karlphillip Could you please help me out what mistakes I have done here ??? So much -ve comments.... I have cleared the issue with that duplicate thing.I am just a school boy and trying to learn C. I have started posting on these forums from past 1 month only trying to learn new things so mistakes are often.But correcting them is the solution not to underrestimate (Sorry if i offend anyone ??)

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach thanks if (hopefully) the question is reopened then please take the corective actions for this question so that i am aware of my mistakes and how to work on that ???

Comment: +1 for asking a relevant question on an interesting topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referring to what was once called the *video refresh buffer*. It's important to state that **Dancing Dolls** [was a virus](http://www.geocities.ws/pratiyush_tango/virus.html) for **DOS**.

Basically, you are expecting video memory to be at address `0xB8000000` on your program's memory. **However**, modern Operating Systems (like Linux/Windows/Mac OS X) provide a virtual memory mechanism that prevents applications from manipulating devices directly. So the `0xB8000000` address your application sees is not the physical address `0xb8000000` that corresponds to the *video refresh buffer*. The last post of [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t280236-p2-accessing-memory-at-0xb800.html) also has some interesting info on this subject.

**Nevertheless**, the technique you are interested in is still valid for 16-bit DOS and is covered on the book [Assembly Language Step-by-step: Programming with DOS and Linux](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471375233). This book has a great section on chapter 6 that explains how this work exactly. The section is named `Inspecting the Video Refresh Buffer with DEBUG`, and has an interesting example that shows how to use **debug.exe** to access the video memory and modify it. I tested it successfully on **cmd.exe** of my Win 7 box.

But if you want to manipulate the screen of a Linux terminal, check [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html#WHATCANWEDO):

> It is a library of functions that manage an application's display on character-cell terminals

Comment: +1 for answering this. Technical nits: I don't find either MS-DOS or [debug.exe](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/09/05/08/169226/RIP-MS-DEBUG-1981---2009) on my Windows 7, except that I have a shortcut to cmd.exe where i have set the MS-DOS icon just for fun... Also, I am pretty sure that the address the OP shows as 0xB8000000 is really notation taken from so called "far pointers" in the DOS days, and that it therefore means B800:0000 (segment selector B800, offset 0000), which means physical address hex B800*10 + 0000 = B8000. However, accessing any of those addresses fails in Windows 7.

Comment: Indeed, I have mistaken `cmd.exe` for MS-DOS. I'll review the steps made on the example and will let you guys know what I did.

Comment: I'm currently using Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bits edition with SP1 and I've installed VS2010 Express, but I don't know exactly where *debug.exe* came from. The example goes like this: fire up `cmd.exe` and execute `cls` to clear the screen. Execute `debug` to open it. Inside *debug* setup the ES register by executing `r es` and then type in `b800`. After that, dump the memory at that location by executing `d es:0` , and then execute the command `d` again to see the next block of memory, and you'll be able to see the text of the prompt at the time *debug* was executed.

Answer (score 4):

I think, most important is to be aware that your question is about an exercise that (apparently) at one time was *designed to be easy and interesting*.

However, that was long ago, and meanwhile both hardware and software has progressed. It is no longer easy to access physical memory. And, at least for the beginner, it is no longer interesting to do that.

Thus, the main goodness points of the exercise have been chopped off by time’s inexorable entropic action.

However, for one who absolutely want to do this exercise, that once-so-easily-accessible hardware can be simulated. Doing such a simulation transparently, so that the student code is the same as if it was for real, is rather difficult and system-dependent. However, if you (the student) just agree to explicitly call some “update” routine in order to simulate the hardware screen update, then it’s more near managable – and thus, old exercises can be reused! :-)

One can then imagine that `main` does some initialization of things, and calls a routine `doTheDancingDolls` with arguments that give access to simulated video memory, and the aforementioned “update” functionality:

```
void doTheDancingDolls(
    curses::Console&            console,
    b8000::DisplayMemorySim&    memorySim
    )
{
    do
    {
        // Whatever - this is where you Do Things to the simulated video memory.

        // Then:
        memorySim.update( console );
    } while( !console.keyboard().keypressIsAvailable() );

    console.keyboard().getKey();    // Consume the keypress.
}
```

… where the `memorySim` object somehow provides the necessary pointer to the simulated video memory  –  a pointer that corresponds to the B8000000 address in the exercise.

That’s the main idea, how to get a starting point for solving this exercise that's designed for now **ANTIQUATED** equipment.

Fleshing it out a bit more, here’s one possible implementation of the video memory simulation (note that this is not code that addresses the things that you were meant to do in the exercise, it just addresses the things that you were never meant to do, but possibly would have to today):

> File **[b8000.h]**

```
#ifndef B8000_H
#define B8000_H
// A simulation of the early PC's 25*80 color text mode video memory.
// The structure of the memory is INTENTIONALLY not modelled in the
// exposed interface. A student can learn from imposing such structure.
//
// Copyright (c) 2011 Alf P. Steinbach.


//------------------------------------------ Dependencies:

#include "curses_plus_plus.h"       // curses::Console
#include <vector>                   // std::vector


//------------------------------------------ Interface:

namespace b8000 {
    typedef unsigned char   Byte;

    class DisplayMemorySim
    {
    private:
        std::vector< Byte >     buf_;

    public:
        enum { nColumns = 80, nLines = 25 };

        DisplayMemorySim(): buf_( 2*nLines*nColumns ) {}

        void* bufferPointer()               { return &buf_[0]; }
        void const* bufferPointer() const   { return &buf_[0]; }

        void update( curses::Console& console ) const
        {
            assert( console.nLines() >= nLines );
            assert( console.nColumns() >= nColumns );
            assert( console.colors().nColors() >= 16 );

            for( int y = 0;  y < nLines;  ++y )
            {
                for( int x = 0;  x < nColumns;  ++x )
                {
                    int const   iCell       = 2*(y*nColumns + x);
                    Byte const  charCode    = buf_[iCell];
                    Byte const  colors      = buf_[iCell + 1];
                    Byte const  fg          = colors & 0xF;
                    Byte const  bg          = colors >> 4;

                    console.colors().setFgBg( fg, bg );
                    console.putAt( x, y, charCode );
                }
            }
            console.updateScreen();
        }
    };
}    // namespace b8000

#endif
```

And the `curses::Console` class might be a simple wrapper over the *curses library*, e.g. like …

> File **[curses_plus_plus.h]**

```
#ifndef CURSES_PLUS_PLUS_H
#define CURSES_PLUS_PLUS_H
// Sort of minimal C++ interface to the "curses" library.
// Copyright (c) 2011 Alf P. Steinbach.


//------------------------------------------ Dependencies:

#include "curses.h"
#if defined( _MSC_VER ) && defined( __PDCURSES__ )
#   pragma comment( lib, "pdcurses.lib" )
#endif

#ifdef  _MSC_VER
#   pragma warning( disable: 4355 ) // 'this' used in member initializer
#endif 

#include <assert.h>         // assert
#include <stddef.h>         // NULL


//------------------------------------------ Interface:

namespace curses {
    class Console;

    namespace detail {
        template< class Number > inline Number square( Number x ) { return x*x; }

        template< class Derived >
        struct SingleInstance
        {
            static int& instanceCount()
            {
                static int n    = 0;
                return n;
            }

            SingleInstance( SingleInstance const& );            // No such.
            SingleInstance& operator=( SingleInstance const& ); // No such.

            SingleInstance()
            {
                ++instanceCount();
                assert(( "can only have one instance at a time", (instanceCount() == 1) ));
            }

            ~SingleInstance() { --instanceCount(); }
        };
    }  // namespace detail

    namespace color {
        #ifdef  _WIN32      // Any Windows, 32-bit or 64-bit.
            int const   lightness   = 0x08;         //  Windows only.      8

            // The portable colors, expressed for Windows systems.
            int const   black           = COLOR_BLACK;                  // 0
            int const   blue            = COLOR_BLUE;                   // 1
            int const   green           = COLOR_GREEN;                  // 2
            int const   cyan            = COLOR_CYAN;                   // 3
            int const   red             = COLOR_RED;                    // 4
            int const   magenta         = COLOR_MAGENTA;                // 5
            int const   yellow          = COLOR_YELLOW | lightness;     // 6 + 8
            int const   white           = COLOR_WHITE | lightness;      // 7 + 8

            // Windows-specific colors.
            int const   gray            = COLOR_BLACK | lightness;
            int const   lightBlue       = COLOR_BLUE | lightness;
            int const   lightGreen      = COLOR_GREEN | lightness;
            int const   lightCyan       = COLOR_CYAN | lightness;
            int const   lightRed        = COLOR_RED | lightness;
            int const   lightMagenta    = COLOR_MAGENTA | lightness;
            int const   brown           = COLOR_YELLOW & ~lightness;    // A bit greenish.
            int const   lightGray       = COLOR_WHITE & ~lightness;
        #else
            // The portable colors, expressed for non-Windows systems.
            int const   black           = COLOR_BLACK;
            int const   blue            = COLOR_BLUE;
            int const   green           = COLOR_GREEN;
            int const   cyan            = COLOR_CYAN;
            int const   red             = COLOR_RED;
            int const   magenta         = COLOR_MAGENTA;
            int const   yellow          = COLOR_YELLOW;
            int const   white           = COLOR_WHITE;
        #endif
    }    // namespace color

    class Colors
        : private detail::SingleInstance< Colors >
    {
    private:
        Colors( Colors const& );                // No such.
        Colors& operator=( Colors const& );     // No such.

        int     n_;
        int     nPairs_;
        int     rawIndexOfPair0_;

        int rawIndexFor( int fg, int bg ) const
        {
            return bg*n_ + fg;
        }

    public:
        int nColors() const         { return n_; }
        int nColorPairs() const     { return nPairs_; }

        int indexFor( int fg, int bg ) const
        {
            int const   rawIndex    = rawIndexFor( fg, bg );

            return 0?0
                : (rawIndex == rawIndexOfPair0_)?   0
                : (rawIndex == 0)?                  rawIndexOfPair0_
                :   rawIndex;
        }

        void setColorPair( int i )
        {
            ::color_set( short( i ), NULL );         //attrset( COLOR_PAIR( i ) );
        }

        void setFgBg( int fg, int bg )
        {
            setColorPair( indexFor( fg, bg ) );
        }

        Colors( Console& )
        {
            ::start_color();    // Initialize color support.

            // Although these look like global constants, they're global variables
            // that are initialized by the call to Curses' `start_color` (above).
            n_ = ::COLORS;  nPairs_ = ::COLOR_PAIRS;
            assert( detail::square( n_ ) <= nPairs_ );   // Our requirement.

            // Obtain curses' default colors, those are at color pair index 0.
            {
                short   fg0  = -1;
                short   bg0  = -1;

                ::pair_content( 0, &fg0, &bg0 );
                assert( fg0 != -1 );
                assert( bg0 != -1 );
                rawIndexOfPair0_ = rawIndexFor( fg0, bg0 );
            }

            // Initialize color pair table to support finding index for given colors.
            // The color pair at index 0 can't be specified (according to docs),
            // so trickery is required. Here like swapping index 0 to elsewhere.
            for( int fg = 0;  fg < n_;  ++fg )
            {
                for( int bg = 0;  bg < n_;  ++bg )
                {
                    int const i = indexFor( fg, bg );

                    if( i == 0 ) { continue; }      // It's initialized already.
                    ::init_pair( short( i ), short( fg ), short( bg ) );
                }
            }
        }
    };

    class Keyboard
        : private detail::SingleInstance< Keyboard >
    {
    private:
        WINDOW*     pCursesWin_;
        bool        isBlocking_;
        int         bufferedKeypress_;
        bool        hasBufferedKeypress_;

        void setBlocking( bool desiredBlocking )
        {
            if( isBlocking_ != desiredBlocking )
            {
                ::nodelay( pCursesWin_, !desiredBlocking );
                isBlocking_ = desiredBlocking;
            }
        }

    public:
        int getKey()
        {
            if( hasBufferedKeypress_ )
            {
                hasBufferedKeypress_ = false;
                return bufferedKeypress_;
            }

            setBlocking( true );
            return ::getch();
        }

        bool keypressIsAvailable()
        {
            if( hasBufferedKeypress_ )  { return true; }

            setBlocking( false );
            int const key = ::getch();
            if( key == ERR )            { return false; }

            hasBufferedKeypress_ = true;
            bufferedKeypress_ = key;
            return true;
        }

        Keyboard( WINDOW& pCursesWin )
            : pCursesWin_( &pCursesWin )
            , isBlocking_( true )
            , hasBufferedKeypress_( false )
        {
            ::keypad( pCursesWin_, true );  // Assemble multi-character sequences into key symbols.
            ::nodelay( pCursesWin_, false );
            assert( isBlocking_ == true );
        }

        ~Keyboard()
        {
            setBlocking( true );
        }
    };

    class Console
        : private detail::SingleInstance< Console >
    {
    private:
        ::WINDOW*   pCursesWin_;
        Colors      colors_;
        Keyboard    keyboard_;

        Console( Console const& );                    // No such.
        Console& operator=( Console const& );         // No such.

        static ::WINDOW* beginWin()
        {
            return ::initscr();
        }

    public:
        // At least with pdcurses in Windows, these numbers are for the
        // console window, i.e. not for its underlying text buffer.
        int nColumns() const    { return ::getmaxx( pCursesWin_ ); }
        int nLines() const      { return ::getmaxy( pCursesWin_ ); }

        Colors& colors() { return colors_; }
        Colors const& colors() const { return colors_; }

        Keyboard& keyboard() { return keyboard_; }
        Keyboard const& keyboard() const { return keyboard_; }

        void putAt( int x, int y, char const s[] )
        {
            ::mvaddstr( y, x, s );
        }

        void putAt( int x, int y, char c )
        {
            ::mvaddch( y, x, c );
        }

        void updateScreen() { ::refresh(); }

        Console()
            : pCursesWin_( beginWin() )
            , colors_( *this )
            , keyboard_( *pCursesWin_ )
        {
            ::cbreak();         // Immediate input (no line buffering).
            ::noecho();         // No input echo.
        }

        ~Console()
        {
            ::endwin();
        }       
    };
}    // namespace curses

#endif
```

To drive it all, in the main program you’d check whether the terminal window (Windows “ console window”) is sufficiently large, etc.:

> File **[main.cpp]**

```
#include "string_util.h"            // strUtil::S
#include "b8000.h"                  // b8000::DisplayMemorySim
#include "curses_plus_plus.h"       // curses::Console

#include <algorithm>                // std::max
#include <assert.h>                 // assert
#include <iostream>                 // std::cerr, std::endl
#include <stdexcept>                // std::runtime_error, std::exception
#include <stdlib.h>                 // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE



void doTheDancingDolls(
    curses::Console&            console,
    b8000::DisplayMemorySim&    memorySim
    )
{
    do
    {
        // Whatever - this is where you Do Things to the simulated video memory.
        // The following three lines are just to see that something's going on here.
        using stringUtil::S;
        static int x = 0;
        console.putAt( 30, 5, S() << "I have now counted to " << ++x << "..." );

        // Then:
        //memorySim.update( console );
    } while( !console.keyboard().keypressIsAvailable() );

    console.keyboard().getKey();    // Consume the keypress.
}



bool throwX( std::string const& s ) { throw std::runtime_error( s ); }

void cppMain()
{
    using std::max;
    using stringUtil::S;

    curses::Console         console;
    enum
    {
        w = b8000::DisplayMemorySim::nColumns,
        h = b8000::DisplayMemorySim::nLines
    };

    (console.colors().nColors() >= 16)
        || throwX( "The console window doesn't support 16 colors." );
    (console.nColumns() >= w)
        || throwX( S() << "The console window has less than " << w << " columns." );
    (console.nLines() >= h)
        || throwX( S()  << "The console window has less than " << h << " lines." );

    namespace color = curses::color;
    console.colors().setFgBg( color::lightRed, color::yellow );
    console.putAt( 30, 0,        "  The Dancing Dolls!  " );
    console.putAt( 30, 1, S() << "  In " << h << "x" << w << " color mode." );
    console.putAt( 30, 3, S() << "  Press ANY key to start...  " );
    console.keyboard().getKey();
    console.putAt( 30, 3, S() << "  Press ANY key to stop...   " );

    b8000::DisplayMemorySim     displayMemorySim;
    doTheDancingDolls( console, displayMemorySim );
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    try
    {
        cppMain();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        cout << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

This post got a bit long, so I’m not adding in the code for the `S()` thing (it's not much code but still).

Anyway, this should provide a starting point for experimentation.

Disclaimer: I just cobbled this together. It’s not very extensively tested. I may, for example, have misunderstood things about the curses library’ keyboard handling –. And I’m *hoping* that it will work also in *nix-land, but I don’t know.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: +1 for an interesting approach. Maybe a little too much for a beginner to grasp but its quite ingenious. This is a C question, by the way.

Comment: oh. hm. thanks about the "C". i didn't notice. Re "ingenious", no it's just straightforward programming (including maybe solving problems that don't exist, just because it's faster to write code to solve it than to delve down into so-so-documented libraries to find out how they work or are meant to work). :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include<conio.h>
    #include<dos.h>
    #define MEMORY_SIZE 3999  // 2 bytes for each character  total char 2000

    void main(){

    char far *vidmem = 0xB8000000; // video memory address row & column zero
    int i,o=0;

    for(i=0;i<=MEMORY_SIZE;i+=2){
        if (o%2==0)
            *( vidmem + i) = 'A';
        else
            *( vidmem + i) = 'a';
    o++;
    }

    while(!kbhit()){

        for(i=0;i<=MEMORY_SIZE;i+=2){       
            if(*( vidmem +i) == 'A')
                *( vidmem + i) = 'a';
            else
                *( vidmem + i) = 'A';
        }
        delay(200); // wait for 200 ms
    }

    }

/* run and compile success fully in Turbo C++ v3.0 non error just warring during running programme u just want to disable it option>>compiler>>message>>portablity */
```

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about actually performing modifications to what is displayed on your screen or do we just take the above assignment as an exercise.

In the latter case it's just looping over the described memory region (0xb8000000 + 25 (rows) * 80 (columns) * 2(bytes/displayed char). Reading the char portion for each displayed character and converting it from upper/lower to lower/upper case.
Conversion is simply done by simple arithmetic. Look at http://www.asciitable.com/ :
E.g: A = 0x41, a = 0x61
So in order to convert one to the other just add/remove 0x20 from the read value.